# How to check if email or phone already exists in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am facing a problem regarding checking of email and phone numbers in my MongoDB database. My code only checks if the email is present in the database but does not respond to the phone.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

require("../db/conn");
const User = require("../model/userSchema");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello World from server lolstar`);
});

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword } = req.body;

  if (!name || !email || !phone || !work || !password || !cpassword) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error: "Please fill your details" });
    }
    try {
        const userExist = await User.findOne({ email: email }, {phone: phone });
        if (userExist)
        {
             return res
          .status(422)
          .json({ error: "Email or Phone number already exists" });
        }
        
        const user = new User({ name, email, phone, work, password, cpassword });
        
        const userRegister = await user.save();
        if (userRegister)
        {
             res.status(201).json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
            }
      
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        
  }
  
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have added my UserSchema file. I don't think it has an error please check if something is wrong here. I want the code to check for both email and phone and then use it for authentication purpose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    work: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    cpassword: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }

})

const User = mongoose.model('USER', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem, more specific than "does not respond to the phone"? What is the expected behaviour, and what behaviour do you observe instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to check if `email` **OR** `phone` exists in database. Your current query checks if **both** of them exist. You should use `$or` operator for your query, like this:

```js
await User.findOne({ "$or": [ { email: email }, { phone: phone} ] });
```

Comment: I tried this code also but it did'nt worked.

Comment: Can you add your schema Model in the question?

Comment: I have added my userSchema

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Welcome. Consider also accepting my answer if it helped you.